# No me deja configurar el height usan media query (Para cuando una persona usa la rotacion en su telofono)

Tags: html, css

Intento ajustar mi web para que cuando alguien use la rotacion en su movil se ajuste la pantalla a su tamano, con el widht lo eh hecho sin porblemas pero con el height no me reconoce que pongo nada.

```
body
{
    background-image: url("imgindex/portada.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 1920px 1080px;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 623px)
{
    body
    {
        background-size: 850px 623px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa tu pregunta e intenta colocar el codigo completo, por ejemplo al final del media query le falta un parentesis, solo editando un poco tu codigo funciona bien el reconocimiento de dimensiones . <style>
body{
background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 700px){

 body{
     background-color: blue;
 }
}
</style>